# Dúvida ao alterar campos automaticamente subSelect

Tags: sql, postgresql

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para mudar todos os campos da minha tabela de vendas.

Modificando o campo preco_total que irá receber a quantidade * preco_unitario.

Lembrando que eu possuo 150 registros na minha tabela venda, então gostaria de modo automático modificar de 1 a 150 automaticamente.

Segue a query utilizada no momento.

```
update
 vendas set preco_total = (select produto.preco_unitario * vendas.quantidade  from vendas inner join produto on vendas.cod_produto = produto.cod_produto
  where vendas.cod_produto = produto.cod_produto) order by cod_venda ;
```

Comment: É para "mudar todos os campos" ou somente o campo preco_total?

Comment: O que você quer dizer com `automaticamente`?

Answer (score 0):

Carlos, alguns *[sgbd](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_gerenciamento_de_banco_de_dados)* implementam "coluna calculada", cujo valor geralmente é calculado em tempo de execução, isto é, quando o conteúdo da coluna é consultado, utilizando coluna(s) da mesma tabela. No PostgreSQL há como simular essa funcionalidade, conforme o tópico "[Computed / calculated columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389/computed-calculated-columns-in-postgresql)".

---

O preço de um produto pode variar ao longo do tempo. Suponha um item vendido em 2/2/2012, quando o preço dele era R$ 2,50 a unidade. Se em uma determinada transação foram vendidas 10 unidades do item, então o preço total do item vendido foi de R$ 25,00.  Mas se o preço unitário desse item foi reajustado para R$ 3,20 em 3/10/2012, aquela venda anterior passará a constar como tendo sido de R$ 32,00. Ou seja, ficou incoerente.

Considerando-se o exposto no parágrafo anterior, sugiro que, sempre que ocorrer uma venda, o preço unitário do item seja copiado da tabela de produtos para a tabela de vendas. Para isso é necessário antes acrescentar a coluna preco_unitario na tabela de vendas. Desta forma, em todo item vendido estará registrado sempre o valor unitário do item no momento da venda.

Após a criação da coluna preco_unitario na tabela de vendas, o código de atualização ficaria simples:

```
-- código #1
UPDATE vendas
  set preco_total= preço_unitario * quantidade
  --where cod_venda = ...
```

---